# Working with overlapping objects in storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I'm working on an app where one of the screens will have a partially transparent overlay in some situations. I'm using a Visual Effect View for this.

I now simply have this visual effect view on top of the other UI elements in my storyboard, but this means having to move it out of the way whenever something else in that view needs changing. Is there a good way to edit such a “sub view” without having it actually be in that view controller's view in a storyboard?

[image: An effect view overlaid on top of some elements]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're really asking for, but you can easily select overlapping elements by shift+right/clicking on the stacked views, then you'll be presented with a popup to select any underlying view.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear. I added a screenshot to try to show what I meant. The shift + right click works, but it's hard to really work with the occluded elements. Ideally I would like to move the overlaid view out of the way (even though it's still “really there” :) or have a way to temporarily hide it.

Comment: Hmm I get it. I don't think that there is a "clean" solution for this, but would be super-interested in case someone has figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the installed check at the bottom of the image:

[image]

Comment: Nice! That seems to do the trick. That, in combination with the document outline to re-select the view later if it needs editing looks like a great solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try,

- Shift + Ctrl + Left Click, or
- Shift + Right Click

on top of the overlapping views in storyboard to get a list.